# why does CSS Float doesnt move my text to right side of my image

Tags: css-float

[snippet of exact problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAagO.png) Problem -

```
[screenshot of website][1]I am creating my personal website. I need my skills text shown next to one of the images using the Float left. it doesn't work as expected.


used float left to align text next to the image-
```

below is the link to code-

codepen.io/gk65408/post/why-does-css-float-doesnt-move-my-text-to-right-side-of-my-image

Comment: You haven't provided enough of your HTML and CSS for us to see what the issue is here. Please post all relevant HTML and CSS code on http://codepen.io/ or https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: codepen link provided

Comment: You made a "post" instead of a "pen" (something I forgot was even an option there). Please make a "pen" of it.

Comment: https://codepen.io/gk65408/pen/OYpbaa

Comment: code pen above and also added snippet of exact problem where the text doesnt float next to image

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because there are no spaces in the text of that paragraph, so the line-box is staying as long as possible, which pushes it below the image.

Either add normal spaces or add [zero-width space characters](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm).